# How to calculate average of values stored in multiple measures in power bi

Tags: powerbi

I have 5 measures. and I want to calculate average of all the 5 measures.

Value in Measure 1:  10
Value in Measure 1:  20
Value in Measure 1:  15
Value in Measure 1:  30
Value in Measure 1:  40

Output : 23 (Average of 10,20,15,30,40)

I am not able to figure out the Dax.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more specific information, here is how to average 5 measures:

```
Average of Measures = 
VAR _m1 = [Measure 1]
VAR _m2 = [Measure 2]
VAR _m3 = [Measure 3]
VAR _m4 = [Measure 4]
VAR _m5 = [Measure 5]
RETURN
    DIVIDE ( 
        _m1 + _m2 + _m3 + _m4 + _m5,
        5
    )
```